# PUT handler not found with serviceStack on IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, servicestack

I am currently using serviceStack for creating REST based services which are hosted in a MVC web application.

So far ServiceStack has been amazing and I have achieved to get most of what I wanted to do working. All this works in IISExpress.

I have now moved over to IIS 7.5 and I get the 400 error that the "Handler for Request not found" when doing a PUT. GET works fine and on  IISExpress both PUT and GET work.

On IISExpress this all worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some info about IIS + PUT/DELETE Verbs taken from the [NancyFx WebFx ASP.NET documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-asp.net):

By default IIS 6 does not support PUT and DELETE verbs. To enable this, you need to add a wildcard mapping to the virtual directory of your Nancy application - read the "IIS6 Extension-less URLs" section in this document: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

You might receive "405 Not allowed" pages while trying to make PUT/DELETE requests on IIS 7/7.5. One way to fix it is to remove the WebDAVModule in the web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>  
</system.webserver>
```

#### Soft PUT / DELETE - Emulating HTTP Verbs

ServiceStack also supports the [X-Http-Method-Override](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Web/HttpHeaders.cs#L7) HTTP Header which will allow you to [simulate a PUT or DELETE with a POST](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/RestWebServiceTests.cs#L86) (and vice-versa).

Comment: Thanks. i already have the remove WebDavModule. Should I try the X-http-method-override? My client is a flex client so I am wondering if that is the issue?

Comment: Tried X-Http-Method-Override and PUT does not work. I tried POST and that does not work either, although from Fiddler both POST and PUT work. I keep getting "Handler for request not found" (404 not found) from my flex client library. Any clues where to look now?

Comment: I am not using NancyFx (didn't know what it was until a few mins ago :))

Comment: It sounds like the flex client is sending a different HTTP Request than what you expect. I would look at packet sniffing the HTTP request (w/ something like Fiddler or WireShark) so you can identify the difference. Could also be CORS related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211930/servicestack-rest-api-and-cors

Comment: Yes, the flex client was sending all sorts of crap but it is now working. Thank you for all your help. Once again, amazing product.