# How to use Servicestack PostFileWithRequest

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to figure out how to post a file to my webservice using servicestack. I have the following code in my client

```
Dim client As JsonServiceClient = New JsonServiceClient(api)
Dim rootpath As String = Server.MapPath(("~/" + "temp"))
Dim filename As String = (Guid.NewGuid.ToString.Substring(0, 7) + FileUpload1.FileName)

rootpath = (rootpath + ("/" + filename))

FileUpload1.SaveAs(rootpath)

Dim fileToUpload = New FileInfo(rootpath)
Dim document As AddIDVerification = New AddIDVerification

document.CountryOfIssue = ddlCountry.SelectedValue
document.ExpiryDate = DocumentExipiry.SelectedDate
document.VerificationMethod = ddlVerificationMethod.SelectedValue

Dim responseD As MTM.DTO.AddIDVerificationResponse = client.PostFileWithRequest(Of DTO.AddIDVerificationResponse)("http://localhost:50044/images/", fileToUpload, document)
```

But no matter what I do I get the error message "Method not allowed". At the moment the server code is written like this

```
Public Class AddIDVerificationService
    Implements IService(Of DTO.AddIDVerification)

    Public Function Execute(orequest As DTO.AddIDVerification) As Object Implements ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService(Of DTO.AddIDVerification).Execute
        Return New DTO.AddIDVerificationResponse With {.Result = "success"}
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see I have not tried to process the file on the server yet. I just want to test the client to make sure it can actually send the file to the server. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're using ServiceStack's Old and now deprecated API, consider moving to [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) for creating future services.

You can look at [ServiceStack's RestFiles](http://www.servicestack.net/RestFiles/#!files) example project for an [example of handling file uploads](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.ServiceInterface/FilesService.cs#L54-L58):

```
foreach (var uploadedFile in base.RequestContext.Files)
{
    var newFilePath = Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, uploadedFile.FileName);
    uploadedFile.SaveTo(newFilePath);
}
```

Which is able to access the collection of uploaded files by inspecting the injected `RequestContext`.

An example of uploading a file is contained in the [RestFiles integration tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.Tests/SyncRestClientTests.cs#L103):

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(api);
var fileToUpload = new FileInfo(FilesRootDir + "TESTUPLOAD.txt");
var response = restClient.PostFile<FilesResponse>(
    "files/Uploads/",fileToUpload,MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileToUpload.Name));
```

Comment: I do plan to move to the new style API but for now I need a quick fix to this problem. For instance the example does not show me how to use the PostFileWithRequest or why I am getting the "Method now allowed". Is there anything I am doing wrong in my code using the old style API?

Comment: If you're getting 405's Method Not Allowed you may need to [remove WebDav](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283694/85785)

Comment: This does not work for me. I added the <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> as instructed but still get the method not allowed. Anyone have anymore ideas?