# Laravel 405 response

Tags: rest, backbone.js, laravel

I'm trying to make an `update` to my app but getting a `Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed` header

Here's my backbone.js code

```
UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'/user'
    ,initialize:function(attributes,options){
        this.fetch()

        this.set('isEmail',true)
        this.sync('update',this,{
            success:function(){
                console.log('sync',arguments)
            }
        })

    }
})
```

The relevant parts of my routes.php file

```
Route::resource('user','UserController');
```

I do have a UserContoller set up with an update method

```
public function update(){
    return 'x';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a resource controller in Laravel, the update method requires an id parameter:

```
public function update($id){ 

}
```

Also check if you're correctly sending the PUT request with id on the model.

Comment: This was essentially the issue. I had to send a request to /user/{something} - which is a bit silly since I'm dealing with a model not a collection and the id is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your web server which does not support PUT (and other http methods used for RESTful services)

[Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP) has special support for this (using POST method which supported by all web servers), which you can enable with:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;

model.save();  // POST to "/collection/id", with "_method=PUT" + header.
```

> If you want to work with a legacy web server that doesn't support Backbone's default REST/HTTP approach, you may choose to turn on Backbone.emulateHTTP. Setting this option will fake PUT, PATCH and DELETE requests with a HTTP POST, setting the X-HTTP-Method-Override header with the true method. If emulateJSON is also on, the true method will be passed as an additional _method parameter.

[ServiceStack Backbone.Todos Delete 405 not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723202/servicestack-backbone-todos-delete-405-not-allowed)