# ServiceStack conditional CROS

Tags: cross-domain, servicestack

I am wondering if it is possible to do conditional cross-domain calls to the service only when a "vendor key" is given to an authorised 3rd party.

**Remotely:**

When the service is called by some authorised remote server, service enables CROS feature, but a "vendor key" is required as a parameter or cookies.

**Locally:**

When the service is called by its own web server, ajax calls are accepted as usual. The "vendor key" parameter is not required when local server hits a CROS service.

Could you please give me some direction on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the implementation of the [EnableCors Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Cors/EnableCorsAttribute.cs#L32) Attribute.

Just change the implementation to look at the incoming `IHttpRequest` and only print the headers when your conditions are met.

You can also do this with a [global request filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) or adhoc, manually - in your [service implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211930/servicestack-rest-api-and-cors).