# jQuery Ajax Request not found, ServiceStack cross domain

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack (9.54), POST request with JQuery AJAX.
cross domain request, prompts an Error "Request not found".

the  service is  self-hosted as windows service. FireWall is off.

I have done, what I read, in ServiceStack for cross domain calls (CORS), but without result.

In the web page,  the   code (which works successfully on localhost)   is  the following.

```
   jQuery.support.cors = true;
         CallTest()
         {
              $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'http://dev.testhost.com:18162/TestAPI',
               data: JSON.stringify(myRequest),
               contentType: 'application/json',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (response, status) {alert(status); },
               error :  error: function (xhr, err) { alert(err);  }
            }
        }
   //in server the code is 
   //1. at appHost
     SetConfig(new ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.EndpointHostConfig
       {

           GlobalResponseHeaders =
           {      //Signal advanced web browsers what HTTP Methods you accept
              { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
              { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
              { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },

           }
  }
    //2. request
     [Route("/TestAPI", "POST")]
     [Route("/TestAPI", "GET")]
   public class myRequest
   {

    public string name { get; set; }
    public address[] addresses  { get; set; }
  }
   public class myResponse
  {
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
   }
  // 3. Service
  [AddHeader(ContentType = ContentType.Json)]
    public myResponse  Post(myRequest request)
    {
       return new myResponse();
    }
```

I debugged with different settings in AppHost code,  based on @mythz previous answers,  [ServiceStack CORS Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741397/servicestack-cors-feature/13750561#13750561)

but it did not work for me.

Update 1: It works for Chrome, not for IE, FIREFOX, OPERA

```
    CHROME Request   
    POST /TestAPI/CreateReservation HTTP/1.1 
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 622
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/json

    CHROME RESPONSE   
     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
     Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
     X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.954 Win32NT/.NET
     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
     Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
     Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

    IE10 Request
    OPTIONS /TestAPI/CreateReservation HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Origin:  localhost:28014
    Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, accept
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
    Host:  
    Content-Length: 0
    DNT: 1
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Pragma: no-cache

    IE10 Response 
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Content-Length: 3
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.954 Win32NT/.NET
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Update 2: Problem solved, it  works, perfect for all browsers tested (Chrome,IE10, Firefox,Opera 12).

Thank you @mythz, @Jon

and  @sroes  from the  stackoverflow question 
 [ServiceStack returns 405 on OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903101/servicestack-returns-405-on-options-request)

step 1. using code from @sroes answer, I replaced in AppHost.Configure the GlobalResponseHeaders,

```
      Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
      RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
      {
         httpRes.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
       {
        httpRes.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        httpRes.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                           "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
         httpRes.End();
        }
      });
```

step 2: based on @mythz  proposal for a route and a method that accepts Options requests. 
 I added in  Routes,   without actually to create any function for Options.

```
   Routes
      .Add<ReservationRequest>("/TestAPI/CreateReservation", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```

Problem solved, it works for me,  ServiceStack rocks !!

thanks a lot.

Update 3 :
 It works also with  the proposed code from @mythz.

At the beginning, the code could not compile, because it could not find  the EndServiceStackRequest().

(an extension method   in the namespace     ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions).

A reference to System.Web also required. Also the httpReq.Method  is httpReq.HttpMethod.

The  most important is  the declaration in Routes for OPTIONS.

Fortunately, it is not necessary to add  an empty method  'Options(RequestDto)`.

```
       using System.Web;
       using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions;
       public override void Configure(Container container)
       {             
         Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature()); 
         this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
         {
           //Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
           if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
               httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest();
         });

         Routes
           .Add<ReservationRequest>("/TestAPI/CreateReservation", "POST, OPTIONS");
       }
```

Also, this question [OPTIONS Verb for Routes with custom CORS headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365577/options-verb-for-routes-with-custom-cors-headers?lq=1)    is about the same issue.

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741397/servicestack-cors-feature

Comment: thanks Jon, I had tried already, as I write in my other comment. 
But it did not work>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this earlier answer [on applying CORS on OPTION HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750561/85785).

You can apply the CORS headers to all **OPTION** requests with a global filter like:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature()); //Registers global CORS Headers

this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) => {
   //Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
    if (httpReq.Method == "OPTIONS") 
        httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest();
});
```

Comment: thanks Demis, but I have read the question and I had  tried already the code. The specific snippet, the RequestFilters is not correct and it cannot find the properties.
 I did corrected the code as
      
        RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
        {
            if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                httpRes.End();
        });
Without results.

Comment: @stefan2410 have a look at all the HTTP Traffic in the web inspector and see which ones are failing.

Comment: I have tested in all browsers, (IE,Firefox,Opera)  they have the same behavior, (not found 404), except Chrome  who send 2 requests,  => first (not found 404), second   SUCCESFULL.   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found      
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.944 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type   =====> SECOND  OF CHROME  =>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: They likely return 404 NotFound because your request DTO is limited to only **GET** or **POST**, try removing the method filter from the route, e.g `[Route("/TestAPI")]` so it works for all HTTP Methods. But this is something the Global RequestFilter would've also allowed.

Comment: @stefan2410 don't post content in comments, just add them to the end of your question.

Comment: NO  with [Route("/TestAPI")],  Chrome, IE return no results but with HTTP/1.1 200 OK, ===>  Firefox, Opera  return HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.  Hope I don't make mistake