# ServiceStack - Rules for Deserialization?

Tags: servicestack

Im trying to do a POST to a service stack endpoint, and the Service Maps the request correctly, but does not Hydrate the RequestDTO, at all.

Service Method

```
  public object Post(PostUpdateContactRequest request)
        {
            // Breakpoint below, has hit with no problem. Everything is in the request null though.
            Contacts upd_contact = Contacts.Load(request.Contactid);
            //..other vlaidation/code/etc
            this.m_repository.PostEditContact(upd_contact);
            return new HttpResult() { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created };
        }
```

RequestDTO

```
 [Route("/contact/update/","POST")]
    public class PostUpdateContactRequest 
    {
        public virtual long Contactid { get; set; }

        public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }

        public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }

        public virtual string Middlename { get; set; }

        public virtual string Suffix { get; set; }

        public virtual string Homephone { get; set; }

        public virtual string Mobilephone { get; set; }

        public virtual string Workphone { get; set; }

        public virtual string Addressline1 { get; set; }

        public virtual string Addressline2 { get; set; }

        public virtual string City { get; set; }

        public virtual string State { get; set; }

        public virtual string Zipcode { get; set; }

        public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }

        public virtual string Email { get; set; }    
    }
```

JSON Data (Generated data not real)

```
{ "Addressline1" : "Ap #638-3472 Dolor. Road",
  "Addressline2" : "",
  "City" : "Forest Lake",
  "Contactid" : "1",
  "Email" : "nibh.sit.amet@gravida.ca",
  "Firstname" : "Amela",
  "Homephone" : "222-222-2222",
  "Lastname" : "Airheart",
  "Middlename" : " S",
  "Mobilephone" : "1-111-111-1111",
  "Nickname" : "Thomas",
  "State" : "TN",
  "Suffix" : "NA",
  "Workphone" : "(888)-888-8888",
  "Zipcode" : "32549"
}
```

Am I missing something?

Updates After More Research:

It appears ContentType + CORs + Datatype in my Jquery Client Are causing conflicts with each other. After reading many things about CORS being in play ( which it is here), everyhting says to use a contentType of 'jsonp',  this causes an HTTP OPTIONS to happen, and my Service Breakpoint no longer gets hit. Obviously, since the verb no longer matches.

Switching to contentType 'json', causes a GET. Again, mismatch of Verb. My service is expecting a POST, for a POST.

All of this to try to get a JSON Object to Post.

using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: jdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('updated!');
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert(xhr);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

If I remove the stuff I added, and let jquery decide these options, I get a POST again, but no JSON Object.  IT switches the content-type to : Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Which my Service isnt looking for, and ignores, and never Deserializes anything. But the Object is trying to be posted! Here are the headers:

Request Header

```
POST /AerosMobileInterface/contact/update/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:7072/AjaxDetail.htm?Contactid=98
Content-Length: 387
Origin: http://localhost:7072
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 500 NullReferenceException
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.932 Win32NT/.NET, ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Sun, 06 Jan 2013 17:13:30 GMT
Content-Length: 9914
```

POST Parameters 
 { "Addressline1" : "Ap #638-3472 Dolor. Road",
      "Addressline2" : "",
      "City" : "Forest Lake",
      "Contactid" : "1",
      "Email" : "nibh.sit.amet@gravida.ca",
      "Firstname" : "Amela",
      "Homephone" : "222-222-2222",
      "Lastname" : "Airheart",
      "Middlename" : " S",
      "Mobilephone" : "1-111-111-1111",
      "Nickname" : "Thomas",
      "State" : "TN",
      "Suffix" : "NA",
      "Workphone" : "(888)-888-8888",
      "Zipcode" : "32549"
    }

It appears I can not get the content Type to behave! I really do not want to hack Jquery, HTTP, and ServiceStack, to do something this simple. There are tons of SO posts where people have had similar problems, and changing the contentType and DataType of the $.ajax function works for them, but its not working here.

Thanks

UPDATE: 
- jdata , which is the variable being passed as the data argument in the $.ajax call, is a {} object. I did a console.log(jdata) to verify that it was actually an object, and not being mistaken for a string, or some other type that would confuse $.ajax. Firebug seems to think that its a valid object, and it produces the correct json projection of that object.

It appears $.ajax is trying to place that object in the query string of the REST call. I was able to alter my service, so that it would no longer accept values in the query string. Which causes the service method not to fire.

Comment: If you are doing a POST and the target Url is not in the same domain (so its a crossdomain request) AND your webservice DOES NOT send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`header , there is NO WAY it can be done. POST is just not possible with jsonp, and POST with regular ajax requires the CORS header or your url to be in the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would invite you to re-read the post.

Comment: To be honest, your post is not very clear, at least to me. Since SO is a Q&A site, what is exactly your question? And could you please point out whether or not your request is a CORS one, or not? This is very important!

Comment: ITs right in the middle of my post.do a CTRL-F for 'CORS'

Comment: Im very sorry you feel that way. I really did my best putting the information in my question. CORs is in play here, and I have done my best following the documentation around that. CORS isnt my issue here, but jQuery seems do what it wants under the hood of $.ajax, despite me setting the options.

Answer (score 0):

So with service stack, posting to rest endpoints seems to work best for me when I'm using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. I would post client side with something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: jdata,
    dataType: 'json',  // Accept: application/json
    success: function (data) {
        alert('updated!');
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        // according to the docs, this isn't 
        // called for cross domain requests...
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        if (status != 'success') alert('there was a error!');
    }
});
```

That said, this will not solve your cross domain issues. You will need to set up Service Stack to support `CORS`, there is a good explanation here:

[servicestack REST API and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211930/servicestack-rest-api-and-cors)