# Calling ServiceStack Service Cross-Domain with Cors Issue

Tags: c#, ajax, servicestack, cors

I am in the process of testing some web services on my local machine.  Because the test page sits on the root at port 80, and the web-services on different ports, I get the following error from Chrome's diagnostic tool:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://PCNAME:8083/PackageSearch. Origin http://PCNAME is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

After doing some searching, I came across the CORS Features of ServiceStack, and put the following attribute on my Web Service:

```
[EnableCors(allowedMethods: "GET, POST")]
```

However, the error still persists.  This is the ajax call:

```
function packageSearch(tourCode) {
            var searchUrl = url + 'PackageSearch';
            var searchData = {
                TourCode: tourCode,
            };
            $.ajax(searchUrl,{
                    data : JSON.stringify(searchData),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                       oTable.fnClearTable();
                   }});
        };
```

Where `url` is `http://PCNAME/`.

**EDIT**

I have even set up the following during the Configuration stage:

```
    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());

        RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
            {
                if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                    httpRes.End();
            });
        base.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            DefaultContentType = "application/json",
            GlobalResponseHeaders = {
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, origin, accept" },
        }
        });
        });
    }   // Configure
```

Comment: Have you deployed your webservices as a console app?

Comment: @BhushanFirake, yes - currently they are stand-alone Self-hosted.

Comment: Then you don't need `cors`

Comment: @BhushanFirake, the error message suggests otherwise.

Comment: You are not using `JSON.Stringify()` while sending data, or have u set `DefaultContentType`?

Comment: Instead of `dataType` in your call, use `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: @BhushanFirake, I have tried with a `DefaultContentType` and with/without `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @BhushanFirake, I  have updated to how it looks currently as I try various things.

Comment: I am not sure about using `dataType` altogether..also, check it may be a typo, semicolon after `TourCode`. Some curly brackets in ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You need a ContentType specified and may have to do a preflight message (OPTIONS) to do the handshake that will allow you to proceed with a cross domain call.

Comment: Also, I had a really weird issue with fiddler intercepting some of my messages and stuff so if you have that open try closing it as well.

Comment: I've added the content-type.  And I didn't see any other examples neededing a preflight message, but interestingly once I had added it, I got 2 error messages on the access-control-origin as opposed to one.

Comment: yes.  Please see edit.  Those headers are set up for ALL services/requests (at least, that's my understanding)

Answer (score 1):

I thought this code looks suspicious:

```
if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    httpRes.End();
```

I think although you are setting all header responses to send CORS headers, you may be short-circuiting the HTTP response headers - they never get sent. You could verify if you use Fiddler to check the exact http response headers sent back.

See this SO answer: [ServiceStack returns 405 on OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903101/servicestack-returns-405-on-options-request)
They send the headers before calling httprequest.end().

You probably have to do:

```
httpRes.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

... before calling response.end()