# Does ServiceStack support CORS over multiple origins?

Tags: servicestack

Using the CorsFeature plugin, how can I support multiple origin domains? I'm not talking about the wildcard "*" here. I'm talking about passing in a list of more than one origins: "http://firstdomain.com, http://seconddomain.com".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ServiceStack's [CorsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs) is just a simple plugin that adds [CORS Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215777/85785) to ServiceStack's Global Response Headers. It supports specifying a number of hosts (or `*` wildcard), e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist = new[]{ "http://domain1.com", "http://domain2.com" }, 
    string allowedMethods = DefaultMethods, 
    string allowedHeaders = DefaultHeaders, 
    bool allowCredentials = false));
```

If you need more customization, then you can simply skip the feature and just add register as many customized response headers as you wish, e.g:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Permit Cross Origin Resource Sharing for multiple Origins:
    base.SetConfig(new HostConfig
    {
        GlobalResponseHeaders = {
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://domain.com" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
        },
    });
}
```

Or using a Global Request or PreRequest Filter:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    var originWhitelist = new[]{ "http://domain1.com", "http://domain2.com" };

    this.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
        var origin = httpReq.Headers.Get("Origin");
        if (originWhitelist.Contains(origin))
        {
            httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, origin);
        }
        httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowMethods, "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
        httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowHeaders, "Content-Type");
    });
}
```

Comment: the second method doesn't work because you're adding the same key twice.

Comment: how can I add more than one origin using the 2nd approach?

Comment: @iwayneo You can't because as you say, it's a dictionary that doesn't allow multiple keys, I've added an example using a PreRequest filter as an alternative.

Comment: Hmmm. using this method I get: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://sdsdsdf.com, http://sdfsdfsdf.com', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://sdsdsdf.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @iwayneo ok yeah updated, this is basically what the [CorsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs) plugin does.

Comment: should that be if (!originWhitelist.Contains(origin))

Comment: @iwayneo no, it's a whitelist?