# CORS and ServiceStack Back End for Internal Web Apps

Tags: servicestack, cors

All,

We are trying to use ServiceStack at work as a backend API for all our internal and forward-facing sites, but we are running into problems. Here are the issues...

Sites

```
 - site1.xyz.com
 - site2.xyx.com
 - etc.xyx.com

API
 - api.xyx.com
```

1) We need a custom request header to handle the authentication. Our apps send an app ID to the API server to authenticate the app, so JSONP is out.

2) Since JSONP is out, we need to support OPTIONS. I have this working on Chrome and IE, but IE is throwing that damn security popup. We can solve that with our internal users, but not with our external users.

If anyone has any suggestions as to how to accomplish this, I'd love to hear them. I wish to hell the CORS spec handled subdomains. If it did, this would work and be sick simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to using CORS, but i did get it working with OPTIONS.

```
public class YourService : Service
{
    ... 
    /// <summary>
    /// CORS support
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Options(YourRequestDto request)
    {
        // return HTTP Code and Location: header for the new resource
        // 204 No Content; The request was processed successfully, but no response body is needed.
        return new HttpResult()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
            Headers = {
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS" } ,
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" }, 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My reference was: [servicestack REST API and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211930/servicestack-rest-api-and-cors)

The web browser should make the OPTIONS request, handled there. Then make the GET, POST, etc after.

This example allows all domains (*), but you could add your own logic to suit.

FYI- i do not think IE has full CORS support until IE 10.